# jQuery/Backbone and Firefox vs Chrome HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Slightly obscure title but here goes ....

I have a Backbone UI that makes a massive amount of calls to an API on page load. It uses Backbone Fetch Cache to cache the GET requests. On Chrome, a cache miss means that when executing many GET requests to the same URL, at the same time, Chrome  causes the duplicate XHRs to wait until the first has finished, then subsequent ones hit the cache.

In Firefox, all XHRs process immediately, even when they are GET requests to the same API endpoint. Refactoring this out of the code would be a pain, so the question is:

**Question:**

Is there an existing method to patch either the sync() part of Backbone or jQuery so that the Chrome behavior is used across all browsers? such that Firefox waits on the first of duplicate GET requests before processing the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `Backbone.ajax` to create a lists of requests and wait for the first to complete before emitting the subsequent ones. For example

```
//cached requests
Backbone.xhrs = {};

Backbone.ajax = function(opts) {
    // cache GET requests, not the others
    if (opts.type!=='GET')
        return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);

    var xhr;

    // issue the request if a cached version does not exist
    if (!Backbone.xhrs[opts.url]) {
        xhr = Backbone.xhrs[opts.url] = Backbone.$.ajax.call(Backbone.$, opts);
    } else {
        xhr = Backbone.xhrs[opts.url].then(function() {
            return Backbone.$.ajax.call(Backbone.$, opts);
        });
    }

    return xhr;
};
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/vexNP/

Comment: Caching isn't the issue, the issue is that many GETs to the same URL fire at the same time (before the first has finished and stored a cache entry). Chrome waits the requests whereas firefox tries to actually execute them all. I think this is a difference in their XHR implementations that I want to normalize.

Comment: Another take on it where requests 2 and beyond fire after the first one has resolved.

Comment: Looks good, i'll try it out. Much cleaner than my current attempt.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help so far nikoshr, i'm using the library from https://github.com/mrappleton/backbone-fetch-cache for caching. With your example above, it seems the cache is only populated once all requests complete ... which sort of defeats the solution. I tried converting your example to an override for Model.fetch() where the first request calls the overridden fetch() (which is the cache override) and populates the cache before allowing subsequent .fetch() calls and their http requests to trigger ... not got it working yet. Any ideas?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aidenbell/d5c151f31e8941b6ce26 is a gist of what I have so far, it's a caffine fuelled mess that actually ignores subsequent requests and returns the original XHR promise, which totally ignores the caching for anything but the first request.

Comment: i'm gonna mark this as accepted. It got me on the right track, the third-party caching library i'm using resolves its promises on XHR complete not cache-updated which I think was causing the issues.